# Asp.Net web forms tabs with caching

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I start to work with asp.Net web forms, I created a page with set of tabs,
I want data to be loaded with select of each tab using jquery 
and also cache data for each tab. 
So what is the best mechanism to load and cache each tab individually in the same page in asp.Net!

Comment: "I created a page with set of tabs"

You'll need to provide more information. What kind of tab control are you using? Why do you have to use jQuery rather than an UpdatePanel to load content on tab click? 

You can cache the object, string, or table used to populate  the tabs using standard caching techniques.

Answer (score 0):

**Page Level Output Caching**
The simplest form of caching, output caching simply keeps a copy of the HTML that was sent in response to a request in memory. Subsequent requests are then sent the cached output until the cache expires, resulting in potentially very large performance gains (depending on how much effort was required to create the original page output—sending cached output is always very fast and fairly constant).

**Implementation**
To implement page output caching, simply add an OutputCache directive to the page.

you will find more details in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx